# What is the command for replacing strings in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

What is the command for replacing strings in CodeIgniter
for example

Original string is www.example.com/imges/fraudsite.html

Replace string is www.example.com/imges/fraudsite.zip

just want to replace all after (dot)

Thanks
Sodmeb

Comment: http://www.php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 3):

You should be more precise with explaining what you want. If you want a route - use `routes.php` file to reroute the original URL to your replacement, either than that - use what @vascowhite suggested in his comment to your question.

If it's routing that you need, in your `routes.php` file in `config` folder of your application add a line:

```
$route['imges/fraudsite.zip'] = "imges/fraudsite.html";
```

If it's just the string you want:

```
$string = "www.example.com/imges/fraudsite.html";
$string = str_replace(".html", ".zip", $string);
```

As you have noted in the comments, you need to change everything that goes beyond the last dot to `zip`, you have to use:

```
$str = "www.example.com/imges/fraudsite.html";
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '.', -1)).".zip";
```

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Really? I see two answers in my answer.

Comment: I'll make you a deal. Remove point 1, however correct it is, and elaborate on vascowhite's answer (instead of the reference), and I'll remove the downvote :-)

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I am not the one who cares about his reputation points too much. But I will leave the first point and will expand my answer

Comment: Regardless of whether you care about the rep points, correcting the spelling in your answer does not aid in answering the actual question. As such, I will edit point 1 out and remove the downvote.

Comment: Well, sometimes people should be pointed at their mistakes, this one is too much popular and editing the question (as I did) does not even make people see it.

Comment: Just trying to keep with the aim of the site. Answering the specific question is the goal. I'm not saying you're wrong to have the impulse to correct him, but that muddying the answer with the correction goes against the purpose of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if there is not .html there is .php then this wont work. I want to change anything that appears after (dot)

Comment: @BrianWarshaw I just try to make people write correctly the titles, it makes search engines parse better and that means less duplicate answers

Comment: @user1684080 you should've noted that in your question. will update the answer in a couple of moments

Comment: @Vlakarados Right--but if you do that in the title by an edit instead of in the answer, then your mission is accomplished and you don't muddy the answer with the unrelated correction :-)

Comment: @BrianWarshaw but that will only affect this topic! Not every other topic they will create! :)

Comment: @Vlakarados Well, we're dirtying it up with comments now--good to have a light-hearted discussion, though. Have a good day, my friend!

Comment: Had same thoughts just now, see you, Brian! :)

Answer (score 0):

$test = "Hello world!";

```
$test = word_censor($test,"Hello","Bye");

echo $test;

//Bye world!
```

Comment: yes but i want to replace the strings after a dot(.) it can be .html, .php etc it will replace all these to .zip